Connecting to Postgres DB running on docker from Quarkus application is failing
I have a Postgres DB running on docker which I created like this
docker run --rm --name my_reative_db -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root -e POSTGRES_DB=my_db -p 5432:5432 postgres:17
When I run the quarkus application , I am getting following error
DDL command failed [io.vertx.pgclient.PgException: FATAL: database "my_db" does not exist (3D000)]
This is my properties file
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=root
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db

When have a normal DB in postgres (not in docker) my application is working properly/
Tried checking the my_db in docker container and it exist

Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository?

Can you run queries from docker exec -it my_reative_db psql -U postgres -d my_db
